# How to use nox with poetry?

Tags: python, pytest, python-poetry

I want to use [nox](https://github.com/theacodes/nox) in my project managed with [poetry](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry).

What is not going well is that installing dev dependency in nox session.

I have the `noxfile.py` as shown below:

```py
import nox
from nox.sessions import Session
from pathlib import Path

__dir__ = Path(__file__).parent.absolute()


@nox.session(python=PYTHON)
def test(session: Session):
    session.install(str(__dir__))  # I want to use dev dependency here
    session.run("pytest")
```

How can I install dev dependency in nox session?

Comment: See [`nox-poetry`](https://github.com/cjolowicz/nox-poetry)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, `session.install` doesn't support `poetry` and `install` just [runs pip](https://github.com/theacodes/nox/blob/bd605aeceb19020d37bdf68f0d2097468753f835/nox/sessions.py#L271) in the shell. You can activate `poetry` with a more general method `session.run`.

Example:

```
@nox.session(python=False)
def tests(session):
    session.run('poetry', 'shell')
    session.run('poetry', 'install')
    session.run('pytest')
```

When you set up session, you can do everything by your own disabling creation of python virtualenv (`python=False`) and activating `poetry`'s one with `poetry shell`.

Comment: starting from version 2019.11.9, `nox` [passes `VIRTUAL_ENV` to](https://github.com/theacodes/nox/pull/245) `poetry` or `pipenv` automatically, so `poetry` can use the virtual env created by nox.

Comment: How would you test multiple python versions? Currently with your solution `python=False` does not seem to allow this.

Answer (score 4):

After some trials and errors and contrary to what I commented in @Yann's answer, it seems that `poetry` ignores the `VIRTUAL_ENV` variable passed by `nox`.

Inspired by the wonderful series [Hypermodern Python](https://cjolowicz.github.io/posts/hypermodern-python-03-linting/) by Claudio Jolowicz, I solved the problem with the following:

```py
@nox.session(python=PYTHON)
def test(session: Session) -> None:
    """
    Run unit tests.

    Arguments:
        session: The Session object.
    """
    args = session.posargs or ["--cov"]
    session.install(".")
    install_with_constraints(
        session,
        "coverage[toml]",
        "pytest",
        "pytest-cov",
        "pytest-mock",
        "pytest-flask",
    )
    session.run("pytest", *args)
```

Here, I'm just using `pip` to install a PEP517 package.

Unfortunately PEP517 installs via `pip` don't support the editable ("-e") switch.

FYI: `install_with_constraints` is the function I borrowed from Claudio, edited to work on Windows:

```py
def install_with_constraints(
    session: Session, *args: str, **kwargs: Any
) -> None:
    """
    Install packages constrained by Poetry's lock file.

    This function is a wrapper for nox.sessions.Session.install. It
    invokes pip to install packages inside of the session's virtualenv.
    Additionally, pip is passed a constraints file generated from
    Poetry's lock file, to ensure that the packages are pinned to the
    versions specified in poetry.lock. This allows you to manage the
    packages as Poetry development dependencies.

    Arguments:
        session: The Session object.
        args: Command-line arguments for pip.
        kwargs: Additional keyword arguments for Session.install.
    """
    req_path = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), os.urandom(24).hex())
    session.run(
        "poetry",
        "export",
        "--dev",
        "--format=requirements.txt",
        f"--output={req_path}",
        external=True,
    )
    session.install(f"--constraint={req_path}", *args, **kwargs)
    os.unlink(req_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to use nox session without poetry, so I used poetry to generate arguments for `session.install()` like this:

```py
@nox.session
def tests(session: nox.sessions.Sessio0n):
    """ Run all tests """
    session.install(*requirements_txt, '.', 'pytest')
    session.run('pytest', 'tests/')


# Get requirements.txt from poetry
import tempfile, subprocess
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w+') as f:
    subprocess.run(f'poetry export --no-interaction --dev --format requirements.txt --without-hashes --output={f.name}', shell=True, check=True)
    f.seek(0)
    requirements_txt = f.readlines()
```

Answer (score -1):

constraints files does not support the same semantics as requirements.

https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11599
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6628

This is work as long as you do not have and package[extra] in your requirements.txt in order to make it work all the time use format="constraints.txt" https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#export